# Sending multiple images in base64 string through REST web service

Tags: java, hibernate, jax-rs

What is the best way to right REST web service to send multiple images using JAVA jax-rs?

Comment: send them as a json array here each array element will contain base64 encoded string of one image.

Comment: No. Send an array of URLs to the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although using base64 strings is an option, there are much better ways to go about sending files in a JAX-RS web service. I personally recommend creating a method that listens for the user to POST an HTTP form. This form could really contain all of the information that you would need to send, as well as identifiers.

This is similar to a method definition that I would use for a web service of this type. It is compatible with Jersey, and it allows the user to send files via a basic HTML form or any POST request. I strongly recommend taking a look at [this article](http://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/) on building Java web services. It doesn't cover the "file uploading" aspect, but it is extremely useful and it helped me learn much more about the functionality of Java web services in general.

```
  @POST
  @Path("/upload")
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  @Produces("text/html")
  public Response uploadFile(
      @FormDataParam("username") String username,
      @FormDataParam("password") String password,
      @FormDataParam("title") String title,
      @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputString,
      @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileInputDetails) {
    String status = null;

    String fileLocation = "/home/user/uploadtest/test.png;
    NumberFormat myFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    myFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
    // Save the file 
    try {
     OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileLocation));
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int bytes = 0;
     long file_size = 0; 
     while ((bytes = fileInputString.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
      file_size += bytes;
     }
     out.flush();  
     out.close();


     status = "File has been uploaded to:" + fileLocation;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.err.println("Unable to save file: "  + fileLocation);
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    return Response.status(200).entity(status).build();
}
```